# Is there a tool to find in c# code everyplace an array is copied

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to find in source code everyplace an array is copied using System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Array destinationArray, int32 Length), regardless of the name of the array.

Is there a tool, or find function in VS 2005 for this?

Comment: What's wrong with the Find functionality built in to the IDE? Search for `Array.Copy`, and search in all files in your project.

Comment: You can also do a regex search: `Array\.Copy\(.*, .*, \d+\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use Ctrl+Shift+F and look for Array.Copy and choose "Entire Solution" for the Look In parameter as well if Find All References doesn't exist in vanilla VS2005.

This won't find the specific overloaded function though.

Answer (score 1):

hover mouse over `Copy` right-click and select 'Find all references'